# MS SQL query on Punch time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datepart

I am trying to retrieve information from 2 database tables (MS SQL DB) on the basis of shift start time (date time format). I want the records with a date range and a specific time of those days, but it seems the query is not working
The query which I wrote is:

```
select p.fullnm 'Fullname',
      t.startdtm 'Start Date/Time'
FROM TIMESHEET t
      join PERSON p on p.personid = t.employeeid
WHERE t.startdtm between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-05'
AND datepart(hh, startdtm) between 6 and 8
AND datepart(mi, startdtm) between 00 and 15
```

What I want is: a list of all employees who worked between 6 am and 7:15 am from 1-Jan till 5-Dec. Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Watch out for the fact that between with dates is not quite as you would expect. If given date-only then it assumes 00:00:00. This is fine for the lower bound but we would naturally have assumed it would use 23:59:59 for the upper but it does not. Impact is to miss out all records from 00:00:00 on the upper bound date. Watch out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
WHERE t.startdtm between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-05'
  AND cast(t.startdtm as time) between '06:00' and '07:15'
```

Comment: HI John, that exactly what I was trying. It works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @sansam you don't state that 2016-12-05 00:00:00 is the intended upper bound so just in case check what happens with records on the 5/12/16. SQL assumes that '2016-12-05' means '2016-12-05 00:00:00:000' meaning your query will not catch data with startdtm on 5/12.

Comment: Removed my erroneous answer, thanks for pointing out. Still feel it is worth mentioning upper bounds + dates consideration as the OP looks to be new at SQL and it would be a good thing to know.